# Detect cursor in current tab outside of LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, dom, lightning-record-page

Hi Im trying to know if a user is idle in a record page tab, and to do it I have placed a LWC in the record page so it could maybe read the outsider events. I have tried using

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {this.handleMouseMove(evt)});
```

But if I change the tab for the record in the same window, it still triggers the mousemove listener, Is there a way I can detect if the mouse is moving in the specific record tab where my lwc is hosted?

[image]

Im trying to detect the red square only mouse movement (if possible the blue one too, but mainly the red one). But my LWC only takes a small part of that area, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The nature of how LWC uses a [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-dom.html) and combined with [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-intro.html) (and its predecessor [Lightning Locker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm), in case you were trying to think of a loophole), makes it impossible to just listen to whatever component you want. What you can do, however, is use the [lightning-platform-workspace-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-workspace-api/documentation) API to listen for tab changes and closures. Unfortunately, this won't give you details about things like "idle" time, but you'll at least be able to determine things like how much time a user has spent on a page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sfdcfox somehow I managed to use a div with absolute positioning and it starts exactly where I want it, I just added a mouselistener to the entire window and tested if x and y were below and at the right of the point where the div was placed.